# Rendering OSM with QGIS for MapServer to use in OpenLayers

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, mapserver, windows

I want to show tiles in OpenLayers offline.

I've installed QGIS 2.0, TileCache, and MapServer on Windows.

Enabled plugin OpenLayers in QGIS.

What kind of data I suppose to extract from QGIS with my own OSM file? And how can I done this process?

I'm new in this map things and I'm now so close I think.